# What is the difference between an application server and application framework?

Tags: jakarta-ee, application-server, application-framework

In the context of Java EE, I am unable to understand difference between an application server and an application framework. Both manage lifecycle of a component, both provide libraries, both provide IoC. What's the difference then?

Answer (score 2):

An application server is typically larger and more pervasive than an application framework. There are several Java EE application servers (Liberty, Wildfly, Thorntail, Glassfish, etc) and all of these can be individually started/stopped, and have one or more applications deployed to them. Typically when an application is deployed to an app server, the application is packaged as a .war or .ear.

An application framework on the other hand is more like a large library. The difference here is that an application framework does *not* require your application to be packaged in a specific way, and an application framework has a one-to-one relationship with the application. The Spring framework is probably the most common example of a Java application framework.